# Summing only positive numbers in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, addition

First of all, thanks for looking at my question.

I only want to add up the positive numbers in the $numbers using a if,else statement.

```
$numbers = array (1, 8, 12, 7, 14, -13, 8, 1, -1, 14, 7);

$total = 0;

if ($numbers < 0 {
    $numbers = 0;
}
elseif (now i want only the positive numbers to add up in the $total.)
```

I'm an first years student and I am trying to understand the logic.

Comment: No loops needed. A combination of [`array_filter()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`array_sum()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$numbers = array (1, 8, 12, 7, 14, -13, 8, 1, -1, 14, 7);

$total = 0;

foreach($numbers as $number)
{
  if($number > 0)
    $total += $number;
}
```

this loops through all elements of the array(foreach = for each number in the array) and checks if the element is bigger than 0, if it is, add it to the `$total`

Comment: foreach, offcourse. Thanks for your time and afford

Answer (score 5):

I'm not gonna give the direct answer, but the way here is you need a simple loop, can be for or a foreach loop, so every iteration you just need to check whether the current number in the loop is grater than zero.

Example:

```
$numbers = array (1, 8, 12, 7, 14, -13, 8, 1, -1, 14, 7);
$total = 0;
foreach($numbers as $number) { // each loop, this `$number` will hold each number inside that array
    if($number > 0) { // if its greater than zero, then make the arithmetic here inside the if block
        // add them up here    
        // $total 
    } else {
       // so if the number is less than zero, it will go to this block
    }
}
```

Or as michael said in the comments, a function also can be used in this purpose:

```
$numbers = array (1, 8, 12, 7, 14, -13, 8, 1, -1, 14, 7);
$total = array_sum(array_filter($numbers, function ($num){
    return $num > 0;
}));
echo $total;
```

Comment: I like the why you explain this to me, thanks! I see the logic now.

Comment: @Greenie sure im glad this shed some light

Comment: @Greenie by the way, don't forget to accept the answer above me, the one that got first, click that check on the left side on his answer. accepting is caring :)